# Binding anonymous functions all over the place

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I generally write code that looks like this (but with many more handlers).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#next").click(function() {
        doStuff();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function() {
        doSomeOtherStuff();
    });

    $("#link").hover(function() {
        doSomeTotallyOtherStuff();
    });
});
```

Is this the best way of doing this? Should I do it differently? [Paul Irish's presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression) suggests it's a bad idea. Is that true?

Comment: `$("#next").click(doStuff);` ?

Comment: Well, yeah, same difference though at the end of the day! I wrote it like that anticipating I might change to named functions.

Comment: It's really not the same, in terms of compression, or in terms of stack traces. `doStuff` will get compressed to something like `ab`, while `function() { doStuff() }` will get compressed to something like `function() { ab() }`. In terms of stack traces, you're muddying the waters with anonymous functions.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read it carefully enough, I thought I'd written $("#next").bind('click' etc. In the real code I have lots of lines of code per closure, not just a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We like to use the object literal pattern and named functions. I'd rewrite your example like this:

```
$(function() {
  Example.somegrouping.init();
});

var Example.somegrouping = {
  init: function() {
    // set up listeners
    $("#next").click(this.onNextClick);
    $("#prev").click(this.onPrevClick);
    $("#link").hover(this.onLinkHover);
  },
  onNextClick: function() {
    // do some stuff
  },
  onPrevClick: function() {
    // do some stuff
  },
  onLinkHover: function() {
    // do some stuff
  }    
};
```

Why? Well, it makes it easier to reuse event handlers in other places without resorting to triggers. The naming of the function can help self-document your code. Testing/debugging is easier. The object literal only adds one entry to the global namespace, so there is little chance for collisions with other scripts your page might be using.

Comment: This is exactly how I've ended up writing stuff, would be interested to hear if there are any botches with it.

Comment: @Rich - works great for us. Code reusability is higher as well. It encourages more modular programming.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine as long you don't do it in a loop or some other code that runs more than once (i.e. a recurring function call). Otherwise there's not much difference between one anon function and one named function. it's when you have 100 identical anonymous functions that's a problem.

ex:

```
$("#someID").click(function(){})
```

is okay,

```
for (var i in somelistofIDs) {
    $(i).click(function(){})
}
```

is not, because you've created 100 anonymous functions instead of one named function.

EDIT

of course, if you're wrapping a single function call in a closure, you're doing it wrong, you can just pass the function itself.

Comment: Yeah, the closure has lots of lines, not just one.

Comment: Your `for` example is a little risky b/c of how closures bind external variables, but as long as you are careful and know what you are doing I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Gabe the problem is that you create 100 instances of the function, rather than just 1.

Answer (score 0):

One reason that it's useful to define your functions the old boring way is that you get names to look at in stack traces.

```
$(function() {
  function nextClickHandler() { ... };

  $('#next-button').click(nextClickHandler);
});
```

It's not safe to use a function name in a function *expression*:

```
  $('#next-button').click(function nextClickHandler() { // DO NOT DO THIS
  });
```

which is sort-of unfortunate but there you go.